# Best place for declaring constructor - Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

When we are adding properties in angular component, whether these properties are declared after or before construtor function. Which is the best place to declare?? Method 1 or Method 2 ? Why?

Method 1

```
class Test{ 
     private variableA;
     constructor(){}
}
```

Method 2:

```
class Test{ 
     constructor(){}
     private variableA;
}
```

Comment: This is opinion based - both will work. It's up to code style and preference. Speaking of, *my* preference is for the first one, just because I'm used to this from other languages where you have fields on top, then constructor, then methods. But it doesn't realistically make any difference in terms of operations.

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting that you interpret private properties as fields. I consider them equivalent to private properties in C#, which I would place below the public properties, which themselves would go below the constructor. Just goes to prove how opinion-based this is. Of course, we all know that there's no such thing as "private" properties / fields in Javascript. For now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practice is to declare your variables before the constructor. After the constructor you usually define your functions. Nevertheless, this is totally up to you and does not have an impact on the functionality.

See the [Typescript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) for more information.